# How to parameterise a plane? Ie. $2x+3y=z$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, plane-geometry, plane-curves, parametrization

I see in the text book, we can equate $x=\cos{}u$, $y=\sin{u}$, $z=v$, but seems to be for cylinders, how do we find a parametric representation of $2x+3y=z$?

Comment: You need two parameters: Ex.,  $x=t,y=s, z=2t+3s$.

Comment: @geetha290krm , sorry what...? so we're just replacing x and y with t & z, what's the point of that.. One of the question told me to find the parameterisation of $2x+3y=z$... /// *edited: I wrote it wrongly as $=$ instead of $=$(correct, per textbook)

Comment: Sorry @AnneBauval , I wrote it wrongly as $z=u$ instead of $z=v$(correct, per textbook)

Answer (score 1):

Let $P:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:2x+3y=z\}$.

$P=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:\exists t\in\mathbb{R}, \exists u\in\mathbb{R},  (x=t)\wedge(y=u)\wedge(z=2t+3u)\}
=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:\exists t\in\mathbb{R}, \exists u\in\mathbb{R},  (x,y,z)=t(1,0,2)+u(0,1,3)\}=\mathbb{R}(1,0,2)+\mathbb{R}(0,1,3)$

Comment: Thanks @Stephane Jaouen,  I just had to translate every symbol... but still don't understand where the t(1,0,2) + u(0,1,3) came from unfortunately... So, what is the parameterised plane based on your answer?

Comment: $(x,y,z)=(t,u,2t+3u)=(t,0,2t)+(0,u,3u)=t(0,1,2)+u(0,1,3)$. $(x,y,z)=(t,u,2t+3u)$ is a parametrization of the plane, which is the directed vector plane generated by the vectors $(1,0,2)$ and $0,1,3)$. You understood ?

Comment: Yep that's helpful, thank you. However, $(x,y,z)=(t,u,2t+3u)$ is not one of the options. So the Parameterisation of $2x+3y=z$ is by substituting $2x=t$, $3y=u$...? // Is there a mistake in your equation "$(t,0,2t)+(0,u,3u)=t(0,1,2)+u(0,1,3)$"? Should it be $(t,0,2t)+(0,u,3u)=t(1,0,2)+u(0,1,3)$?

Comment: You can parameterise the plane with two parameters t and u. x=t and y=u and then z is expressed as a function of the two parameters t and u. And you are right: $(t,0,2t)+(0,u,3u)=t(1,0,2)+u(0,1,3)$. :)

Comment: Thank you. If we are expressing it as a function of t and u, shouldn't it then just be a direct replacement? Ie. $x=t, y=u, z=2t+3u$? // If it is so, then what scenario will this be beneficial, aren't we just substituting one algebra for another..?

Comment: It's ways of seeing the same things differently. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}, (x,y,z) \mapsto 2x+3y-z$. And $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3, (t,u) \mapsto (t,u,2t+3u)$. In one case $P=f^{-1}(0)$; in the other, $P=\Phi(\mathbb{R}^2)$.